# Stop automatic cleaning of js-cache in OTRS?

Tags: otrs

Folder `js-cache` in OTRS 6.0.22 is cleaned every two minutes.
I mean: `/otrs/var/httpd/htdocs/js/js-cache`.
Is there any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

This can only be misconfiguration. Check the SysConfig:

```
Daemon::SchedulerCronTaskManager::Task###LoaderCacheDelete
```

Should only run every Sunday at 12:30 AM.